# Shopping-list question with lots of link-only answers

Tags: discussion, flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12408146/1105376) question recently popped up on SO.  I of course voted to close it but (at this time) it has *five* link-only answers. Not surprising considering the question, but still.

Should I flag each answer? Or should I flag just one, assuming a mod will notice all the rest? Or just leave them alone?

**Edit:** or, report it here and watch the magic happen?

Comment: It's been deleted. Thanks @Kev.

Comment: ...and is now gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the OP is pretty much asking for links to sites. I dislike (but that generally means sneer quietly behind my monitor and nothing else) when answers are link only and try to provide a better one with the relevant code, but:

> I want to know if there is any web site where I can download free android application source code, so I can learn from them, especially for design issues.

really does say - give me a link!

This is a merging or a poor (not good fit for Q&A) question with answers that generally aren't up to par on SO. It's a circular reference :)

Comment: It also really does say "I'm too lazy to search for such sites myself."

Comment: @AaronBertrand Totally and utterly agree. The answer wasn't an indication of my thoughts on the personality traits of the OP however, they would likely get flagged - nothing annoys me more than someone who can't throw three search terms into google - but I *try* not to let my thoughts affect my answer when I post one :)